# Inefficient Query

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT submissions.created_at, guests.accepted
FROM submission
INNER JOIN guests
ON guests.event_id = 1
ORDER BY submissions.created_at ASC;
```

Currently this query is taking a long time to run (may not even return everything).
What I am trying to accomplish:

Grab the field submissions.created at and guests.accepted (the two are linked by a submission_id) 
given a certain event_id (event 1 for example).

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: You've omissed the join condition on the submission_id of those tables. That won't get generated automatically.

Comment: @VMai 'omissed'; a beautiful hybrid of 'omitted' and 'missed'!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to give the JOIN condition in your query. Try this:

```
SELECT submissions.created_at, guests.accepted
FROM submission s
INNER JOIN guests g on g.event_id = s.submissions_id
where guests.event_id = 1
ORDER BY submissions.created_at ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT submissions.created_at, guests.accepted
FROM submission
INNER JOIN guests
ON guests.(column to match against) = submissions.(column to match on)
where guests.event_id=1
ORDER BY submissions.created_at ASC;
```

As many others here have already said, your join is a little goofed.  It's attempting to join the one row that matches in the guests table against every single row in the submission column.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do your join like this :

```
Inner join guest on guest.event_id = submissions_id
where guest.event_id = 1
```

When you join you need to join on two columns from different table (most of the time id columns)
You can read the [MySQL example](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) for more explanation. And here is the link to the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: @Barmar I prefer it in the `ON` clause, as it is related to the table `guest`.. why put it in the `WHERE`?

Comment: @Arth Because it doesn't relate to the conditions that relate the two tables. `ON` is for joining conditions, `WHERE` is for single-table conditions. An exception is made for `LEFT JOIN`, where conditions on the right-hand table need to be in the `ON` clause so they don't cause the rows to be filtered out of the results.

Comment: @Barmar Pish! Says who, it is way more readable in a complex query to put the conditions of the table in there relative JOIN.. I do it all the time. Makes indexing a lot easier. It kind of is a joining condition too, because you are joining to rows that match all the on clause.

Comment: @BenLefebvre You have linked to the wrong database system, this qu is MySql.

Comment: Are we sure we even KNOW the joining condition?  joining events on submissions doesn't particularly make sense to me, but I suppose it's possible...could just as easily be a foreign key or so....